# Custom aggregated query with spring boot data REST

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm pretty new to Spring Boot and Spring Data Rest and HATEOAS. I'm able to create a REST API with CRUD capability on an entity (say `Device`, entity having a few properties, including one called `manufacturer`), and interact with the API (get/add/update/delete/patch `device`) "out of the Spring Boot box".

I now want to call an API endpoint to get an aggregated view of the device repository that, in short, returns the result of the query `select manufacturer, count(*) from devices group by manufacturer`. Is this doable with spring data rest or it needs to be done with JPA? or should I define a specific entity having these two fields (device_manufacturer, count)?

Thanks